# What to think about when designing a simple GUI for a quiz game

Tags: iphone, gui, accessibility

I am coming close to finish my first iPhone game ever, as a matter of fact also my first programming experience ever, which is a quiz game. I have all the functionality i want and is currently polishing it both from a code point of view as well as looking at the GUI.

My initial idea was not to use any specific graphics but rather focus on the game experience and simplicity and by that only using background color, orange, and white text as well as buttons. The design is based on that all ages, from learning to read, should be able to host and play this game.

However, as i am now getting close to the finish line i am starting to think what is needed from a GUI point of view.

I would like to ask for some advice what to think about when designing a GUI. Is it considered OK without any 'fancy' graphics, what is the risk without it etc.?

Also, what colors goes well together if i choose to use a simple GUI. I am thinking about color blindness etc.

In other words how do i design a good and effective GUI for a simple game as mine?

Thanks

Comment: You might be able to find some more answers here: http://ui.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would also keep the design simple, if you are trying to make it too fancy you might end up making it feel messy.

For the colors I would suggest this site : http://kuler.adobe.com/

Make sure your menu is straight forward and simple too use. 
To avoid color blindness issues try not too use colors like green and red together, try looking at this for the exact schemes : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness

Good luck !

Answer (score 5):

I hate to say it, but a good (or bad) UI can make (or break) your application. If possible, get a group of beta-testers together (your friends who all have iPhones?), give them a free copy of your game, and drill them about the UI.

Assuming you have more than one person who's willing to do this, you can easily see trends in good (and bad).

Beyond that, I would **pick up a book or two about usability;** that's more important than GUI, imo. If you have a great, usable UI (albeit not sparklingly beautiful), people will like your game. But if you have amazing graphics and poor usability, people will put your game down quickly.

As for colour-blindness, just don't put red on a green background (or vice versa) and you're good to go. If people who are colour-blind are playing your game (and complaining), that's a great sign that you're getting lots of users.

**Edit:** some materials that might be useful:
- [Dive into Accessibility](http://diveintoaccessibility.org/) (30 day accessibility "course"), i.e. usability for disabilities

There's a book I read, but I can't find it; try googling for good resources.

Comment: Thanks for this, both answers so far, have been very good answers. Could you recommend a book about usability as i am not sure what to search for? Also i have currently the most simple GUI possible, only text and buttons.